# UITableView: Section identifier problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have an UITableview with a lot of sections with a dynamic amount of rows with a dynamic height.
Now i got the following Problem:

`[indexPath section]` returns the value of the (latest/ lowest/ highest-value) section in the view.
Now i have a section witch is very small and i can unfortunately "see" 3 sections in one time. How can i identify the section on top? Any ideas. 
I need it because in every section are buttons which cause a change of the amount of Rows in the section ( depending on the section). Sometimes i increase the amount of Rows for wrong sections because i cannot identify the 'upper' section.

I hope i described it good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the visible cells using the `visibleCells` method of the table view. You will need to sort the array to be sure.

```
NSArray * visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
NSArray * sortedVisibleCells = [visibleCells sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSIndexPath * indexPath1 = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:obj1];
    NSIndexPath * indexPath2 = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:obj2];

    return [indexPath1 compare:indexPath2];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", [self.tableView indexPathForCell:[sortedVisibleCells objectAtIndex:0]]);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. it works now, the only thing i had to change in your code was that it breaks for section 0 and row 0 because the value is nil and NSLog couldn't handle it.